# How do I approach array properties when I need an array to have an interval in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, properties, setter, getter

I am extremely new to C# and am still trying to wrap my head around some of its core concepts.First time posting a question to StackOverflow.

So this is what I need help with:

> Make a property for: private string array; : so that:
>   "Each element of an array needs to be >=0 and <=10"

Should I run it through for, and then set array=value for each element or what?

This is what I did:

```
private string array;
 public int[] Array
        {
            get { return array; } //-is this part good for the task?
            set
            {
                //what do I do here to make sure the elements are withing the 
                //given interval?

            }
        }
```

Comment: C# is strongly typed. Why do you have a string array with numbers in it? Numbers between 0 and 10 only should be stored as byte. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: A property can only check for the assignment of a whole array, but it will not be activated is someone is assigning single value to an array position. doesn't the text say more? Can this property also be an [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)? Because an indexer would allow you to check the validity of assignments to any array position.

Comment: Note that even if you validate that every element is *currently* in the range [0, 10] it won't prevent the array from being mutated afterwards - unless you clone it.

Comment: Yes, the specification is not clear. Is the whole array assignable or is it read-only and created internally?

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you need ([Demo](https://rextester.com/LWWIB60697)):

```
public class myClass
{
    private int[] _Array = new int[10];

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return _Array[index]; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0 && value <= 10)
                _Array[index] = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        myClass m = new myClass();
        m[0] = 1;
        m[1] = 12;
        Console.WriteLine(m[0]); // outputs 1
        Console.WriteLine(m[1]); // outputs default value 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Other options would be to clip the value (`Math.Max(0, Math.Min(10, value))`) or to throw an exception. Again, the specification is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this

```
private int[] _privateArray;
public int[] PublicArray
{
    get
    {
        return _privateArray;
    }
    set
    {
        foreach (int val in value)
        {
            if (val < 0 || val > 10) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        // if you get to here you can set value
        _privateArray = (int[])value.Clone();
    }
}
```

please note private property and public property must be same type

Comment: That doesn't really help much, because the array can be mutated afterwards.